Text to the right of 'Add to Cart' button
Wordpress/Woocommerce. Website add to cart button text
How would I remove or change the text to the right of the add to cart button. Can't seem to find it anywhere.  Checked plugins, php files, etc. Must just be default somewhere.
Text next to add to cart 1
